# JWrapper EXE on Windows 8 requires "Run as Administrator..."

Tags: java, windows-8, windows-firewall

**Short version:**

We are producing an EXE for Windows 8 that executes an internal BAT file on startup. Currently, the EXE/BAT functionality requires the user to right-click and "Run as Administrator...". We want it to work with a simple double-click. i.e. no interaction when invoked by a user or program.

**Long version:**

We are using the latest version of [JWrapper](http://www.jwrapper.com/) to generate a EXE. As part of startup, the EXE calls a BAT file. The BAT file enables firewall rules. The rules look vaguely like:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=acmeCompanyName program=AcmeCompany.exe Action=Allow Dir=In protocol=6 Profile=Any
```

This all works on Win7. We are testing the EXE on Windows 8 with an account that has admin privileges. Microsoft [SmartScreen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SmartScreen) is disabled. [User Account Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) (UAC) is disabled. (We are aware of a [registry issue with UAC](http://www.eightforums.com/system-security/2434-disable-uac-completely.html) but the regedit solution seems too brittle).

In the JWrapper config XML, we have the following:

```
<InstallType>CurrentUser</InstallType>
<WindowsElevation>RequireAdministrator</WindowsElevation>
```

When we double-click on the EXE, it starts, but the BAT file fails to write the firewall rules. If we right-click on the EXE, and choose "Run as Administrator...", it works.

**Question:**

How can we achieve the double-click solution?

Comment: Have you tried posting this in the [JWrapper forums](http://www.jwrapper.com/forum.html)? They're pretty helpful there:

Comment: I agree they are helpful (and that JWrapper is a great tool). Posting here first as I may need to put bounty on it.

Answer (score 2):

We solved it, with help from JWrapper support. Our solution is to use the following values in the JWrapper config XML:

```
<WindowsElevation>RequireAdministrator</WindowsElevation>
<WindowsElevationUiAccess>true</WindowsElevationUiAccess>
<InstallType>AllUsers</InstallType>
```

**Edit:**

For apps that want to install for CurrentUser (not AllUsers), this approach works as well:

- create a new virtual app (e.g. *InstallFirewallRules*) that calls "`netsh ...`" directly from Java. There is no need to run a BAT file.
- create a `JWrapperPostInstallApp`. This app should call *InstallFirewallRules* using `JWSystem.forkVirtualApp()` with `elevateToAdmin = true`